# AWS Toolkit Eclipse Plugin no Global Configuration

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, eclipse

So I have always used Eclipse for development and I just got myself a more capable computer. While resetting all my environments and installing the AWS Eclipse Plugin. However, in the current plugin, there are no 'Global Configuration' option. Am I missing something? Was there some type of update? I have tried to re-install the AWS toolkit multiple times and I am somewhat lost now.

Running Windows 11 (Eclipse Version: 2022-12 (4.26.0)), if that is worth noting. This below is what it currently looks like.

[image]

This error in the Eclipse error log may be relevant.

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/databinding/beans/PojoObservables
    at com.amazonaws.eclipse.core.ui.setupwizard.ConfigureAccountWizardPage.createControl(ConfigureAccountWizardPage.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard.createPageControls(Wizard.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createPageControls(WizardDialog.java:744)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createContents(WizardDialog.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1094)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:788)
    at com.amazonaws.eclipse.core.ui.setupwizard.InitialSetupUtils$1.run(InitialSetupUtils.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4029)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3645)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:643)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.databinding.beans.PojoObservables cannot be found by com.amazonaws.eclipse.core_2.3.1.v201807201743
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.generateException(BundleLoader.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass0(BundleLoader.java:536)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:416)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 33 more
```

Has anyone faced this issue before? Any help that can be provided would be amazingly appreciated!

Comment: The `PojoObservables` class the plug-in is looking for is no longer part of Eclipse, the plug-in needs to be updated.

Comment: @greg-449 That is very, probably it then. Many thanks, I'm surprised I've seem absolutely nothing about this.

Comment: The class is obsolete since 2014 and in the list of removed APIs: https://help.eclipse.org/latest/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fporting%2Fremovals.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone.The AWS Eclipse plugin has been deprecated.